# Unable to connect to lightswitch server

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch

I try to get LightSwitch running under Visual Studio 2013 Premium. For that I created an app based on the HTML template and then added my database conenction (localdb).

When I try to start the app I get the following error

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Es kann keine Verbindung mit LightSwitch Server hergestellt werden.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Which translates roughly to

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Unable to connect to the LightSwitch Server.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? If you need more information, just ask :)

Answer (score 0):

I've never created a LightSwitch (LS) web project but for the LS desktop apps you need to add a Admin account when you go to publish. The account requires a valid domain name ex: domain\user. When you launch the app for the first time, i believe you need to register your users. So you need to be logged in AS the admin account you supplied during publishing. If the account name you specified as the admin is different from your login, that could cause that error.

Comment: The publishing works perfect, it is the debugging, what causes problems :(

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I added the server name to my hosts file in the system32 folder:

Located here:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

for example:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

10.0.1.1/SERVERNAME
MYSERVER/SERVERNAME
```

to edit this document, open up notepad as an administrator, and then go to the file location. its important to do this otherwise it wont save...

Hope this helps!